# why my router have only 2 options?

Tags: router, port-forwarding

I am trying to open the ports of my interner but upon entering the router I only have these two options and I cannot do anything else. For what is this? [image: Click here!]

Comment: It is due to the fact your router does not support port forwarding or you are not logged into a privileged user. This device is likely supplied by your ISP with a modified firmware.

Comment: Use the account which have administrative permissions (proper login/password when connecting to router's interface).

Comment: @Akina - Please read my entire comment.  I recognized the user likely logged in with the wrong account

Comment: @ThomasCaycedoMartinez - Comments are not answers, sadly, you have not provided enough information to properly answer your question.

Comment: @Ramhound Don't worry, I just wanted to know why this happened, and you're right.

Comment: This is a restricted page. Instructions when logging in correctly [are here](https://www.cfos.de/en/cfos-personal-net/port-forwarding/tp-link-tl-wr740n.htm).